# Codeigniter - make own constant instead of using config/constant.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

Is there any possibility we can make our own `constants` and does the work instead of using `constants.php` in `config` folder? Cause I wanted to create some `constants` and my `constants.php` is too long, is there any possibility I can make a `custom_constants.php`?

Comment: You must be using some sort of framework; `config/constants.php` does not exist by default. And of course you can make your own constants -- they'll probably even overwrite your framework's built-in ones.

Comment: I am using `Codeigniter` Framework

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of `config.php` you can put:

`require_once(APPPATH . 'some_folder/more_constants.php')`;

and it will be loaded for the CodeIgniter instance on all pages.

Take caution not to re-define any CodeIgniter constants in `application/config/constants.php` or you will get a notice.

Further I think you should reevaluate why you have so many constants. Typically constants are just for paths and set-in-stone vars so I bet you could get away with just creating a new config file and using the config class: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html